# Why does IEnumerable<thing> Select run everytime?

Tags: c#, linq

I took a second to look why my app had terrible performance. All i did was pause the debugger twice and i found it.

Is there a practical reason why it runs my code everytime? The only way i know to prevent this is to add ToArray() at the end. I guess i need to revise all my code and make sure they return arrays?

Online demo http://ideone.com/EUfJN

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Test
{

    static void Main()
    {
        string[] test = new string[] { "a", "sdj", "bb", "d444"};
        var expensivePrint = false;
        IEnumerable<int> ls = test.Select(s => { if (expensivePrint) { Console.WriteLine("Doing expensive math"); } return s.Length; });
        expensivePrint = true;
        foreach (var v in ls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("If you dont think it does it everytime, lets try it again");
        foreach (var v in ls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Doing expensive math
1
Doing expensive math
3
Doing expensive math
2
Doing expensive math
4
If you dont think it does it everytime, lets try it again
Doing expensive math
1
Doing expensive math
3
Doing expensive math
2
Doing expensive math
4
```

Comment: It enumerated twice because you enumerated it twice. What exactly did you expect to happen here?

Comment: I've been reading through @jonskeet blog (found [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx)) on linq and I must say it's definitely worth the effort, a *must* read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ has lazy evaluation methods and `Select` is one of them.

And the thing is you are using `foreach` two times and it prints the values two times.

Answer (score 5):

Enumerables evaluate lazily (only when required). Add a .ToList() after the select and it will force evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

The *Select* causes the iterator to be... iterated.

If it is expensive to build the result, you can .ToList() the result once, then use that list going forward.

```
List<int> resultAsList = ls.ToList();
// Use resultAsList in each of the foreach statements
```

Comment: He could leave it was `IEnumerable<int>` and still call `ToList` on the query object.

Comment: Sure.  The way I wrote it, it is clearer what's happening imho.  But you're right.  Your way, `ls` would be an `IEnumerable<int>` backed by a list rather than by the Linq expression.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building the query

```
IEnumerable<int> ls = test.Select(s => { if (expensivePrint) { Console.WriteLine("Doing expensive math"); } return s.Length; });
```

It actually does not EXECUTE and cache the result as you are apparently expecting. This is called "deffered execution".

It just builds the query. The execution of the query actually takes place when the `foreach` statement is called on the query.

If you call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` or `Sum()` or `Average()` or any operator of the kind on your query, it will however execute it IMMEDIATELY.

The best thing to do if you want to keep the result of the query, is to cache it in a array or list by calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` and to enumerate on this list or array rather than on the constructed query.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation of [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action.  The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

By iterating the result of the `Select` method, the query is executed.  `foreach` is one way to iterate that result.  `ToArray` is another.

---

> Is there a practical reason why it runs my code everytime?

Yes, if the result was not deferred, then more iteration would be performed than necessary:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000)
  .Select(x => x.ToString())
  .Where(s => s.Length == 6)
  .Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Linq's deferred execution. If you need a concise yet complete explanation, read this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/03/16/understanding-linq-to-objects-6-deferred-execution.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `.ToArray()` which will `return int[]` for you and will give better performance

Reason why `int[]` because it will be declare and create at once, well as the `List<T>` wil be created one by one at runtime

```
int[] array = test.Select(s =>
{
   if (expensivePrint)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Doing expensive math");
   }
   return s.Length;
}).ToArray();
```